# How do I connect application running as "local admin" to remote database using SQL Authentication, without "sysadmin" rights on the server

Tags: sql-server, authentication, system-administration

I am trying to connect to a remote database with SQL authentication, from an application running as “local admin” on another machine.

I have an SQL database on one machine.

I have mixed mode authentication.

I have an application that launches on another machine, which runs as “local admin”, which means it has to connect to the database with SQL authentication.

As far I know, the application cannot run as anything other than a “local admin” account because it is launched remotely using WMI. I do not want to require as service running on the machine in order to launch the application.

But it can only connect to the database if I give the SQL account “sysadmin” rights on the “server”, so that the “local admin” account can login to the database.

Is there a way to allow an application running as “local admin” to login to the database without being “sysadmin”?

Comment: No special rights are necessary at all to log in to SQL Server, as long as you have a server login and a user mapped to that login in the database. The account may need additional permissions to do specific things in whatever database you're accessing (as you won't get very far with just login rights), but that's another matter altogether. It is never necessary to hand out sysadmin permissions (unless, of course, the account really needs to do something only sysadmins are permitted to do).

Comment: thanks Jeroen, the problem was that the database account was set up as SQL user "without" login in the database.

Comment: Did you map the SQL user to the database you are attempting to access?

Comment: @Ross, yes. but the database already had an account of the same name, which was "SQL account without login" so I had to remove it, so when I added the account to the server, it would recreate it in the database with login.

Answer (score 0):

the database already had an account of the same name, which was "SQL account without login" so I had to remove it, so when I added the account to the server, it would recreate it in the database with login.